# Recover to windows 7 factory OS from windows 8.1, dell xps

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, partition-recovery, dell-xps

I have dell xps 15, it came with windows 7 in its recovery partition, and I upgraded to windows 8.1.
Now I want to recover to windows 7 again from the recovery partition, but It didn't work, it always ask me to insert to drive or recovery dvd.
How to start the reset to factory settings from windows 8.1 to make it install windows 7 from the recovery partition?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the prompt for the recovery drive, it sounds like, you actually need a recovery disk one you would have created yourself while Windows 7 was still installed using Dell software.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have this recovery disk, is there any way to start the recovery from the recovery partition without it?

Comment: No;  Just use a Windows 7 installation disk of the same type as your license is for and install Windows 7.